# Script to add a number of Objects, Cameras to a scene but cannot rename data objects?

Tags: python, objects, camera

I am adding a few objects to a scene. Super basic stuff.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(radius=6, fill_type='TRIFAN', location=[0,0,0])
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, location=[0,0,5])
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(view_align=False, location=[0,10,20], rotation=[0.436,0,3.1415927410125732])

bpy.data.objects[0].name = 'Plane1'
bpy.data.objects[1].name = 'Object1'
bpy.data.objects[2].name = 'Object2'
```

This works for renaming items: 1 and 2 in the bpy.data.objects array, but not item at 0? i.e. the circle primitive is not renamed ... this happens with whatever is at [0]?

Investigating this I have also tried the following:

```
if 'Cube' in bpy.data.meshes:
    bpy.data.meshes.data.meshes['Cube'].name = 'Object1'
```

In this case the 'if' condition doesn't seem to get satisfied at all and none of the objects are renamed.

What am I doing wrong with my approach to the 'Data API' is it Async? ... I think not? But it feels like things are not as procedural as I might be assuming they are? Wishing the Data Api docs were more fleshed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running a `primitive_add` operator the context object will be the newly created object.

```
import bpy
from math import pi
context = bpy.context

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(radius=6,
                                  fill_type='TRIFAN',
                                  location=[0, 0, 0])
plane = context.object
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1,
                                location=[0, 0, 5])
cube = context.object
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(view_align=False,
                          location=[0, 10, 20],
                          rotation=[0.436, 0, pi])
camera = context.object
plane.name = 'Plane1'
cube.name = 'Object1'
camera.name = 'Object2'
```

If you want to rename the data part of above objects

```
plane.data.name = "blah" #  rename plane mesh
camera.data.name = "blah"
```

Using indexes from the collections is IMO not the way to go.  Running

```
[o.name for o in bpy.data.objects]
```

in the py console, indicates the objects in this collection are internally sorted by name.  A "better" approach may be

```
[o.name for o in bpy.context.scene.objects]
```

but still wouldn't recommend this approach.